# An anonymous runnable prevents Android from garbage-collecting the activity in which it's defined

Tags: java, android, anonymous-class

While reading [the example](https://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/), I noticed that the author created `Runnable task` in `MyActivity`. If I close the activity, the system won't be able to garbage-collect it because the runnable contains an implicit reference to MyActivity, right? The activity will be alive as long as the runnable works.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: so make your `Runnable` static: it will no have the implicit reference to your activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems correct.

From your link (although talking about AsyncTask, not anonymous Runnable):

> if it is an inner class of your Activity/Fragment, it holds an implicit reference to it, which is bad practice, because Activity/Fragment can be destroyed on configuration change, but they will be kept in memory while worker thread is alive; **if** it is declared as standalone or **static inner class** and **you are using reference to a Context to update views**, you should always **check whether it is null or not**"

Comment: BTW, thanks for the link. I'm reading right now, it's very good.